# TODAY() function not working in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate the number of days that have elapsed from the start date. For that, I am using the function `=TODAY()-C3`. You can see in the image that `C3` contains the start date. But the answer is coming **`03-Jan-00`**. If I just write `=TODAY()` or `=TODAY()+5` it is working.

I am attaching the screenshot and a [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQ7djK1BRICjFfAaAG0T08snuRZhcU-k/view?usp=share_link) link where you can see the screen recording of the problem for a better understanding.

[image]

Comment: your cell D3 is formatted as a date. Format it as a number and it will display `3` as expected ... Excel is not always too smart when picking an autoformat for a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Works as shown:

[image]

Just note that cell c1 is formatted as number.

The reason that you need to format as a number is because that is the result you expect. ie the difference between two dates is a number of days, not a day with month and year.